# In Java's MongoDB driver, how do I update a document within a list of documents?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a document already in the database that can be represented as follows:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    field1: "hello"
    field2: 2,
    listField: [
        {
            subField1: ...,
            subField2: ...
        },
        {
            subField1: ...,
            subField2: ...
        }
    ]
}
```

I have constructed another document that will be used to update the document with an id of 1. It can be represented as follows:

```
Document newDocument = {
    field1: "goodbye",
    field3: 3,
    listField: [
        {
            subfield3: ...
        },
        {
            subfield3: ...
        }
    ]
}
```

The expected result is as follows:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    field1: "goodbye"
    field2: 2,
    field3: 3,
    listField: [
        {
            subField1: ...,
            subField2: ...,
            subField3: ...
        },
        {
            subField1: ...,
            subField2: ...,
            subField3: ...
        }
    ]
}
```

How can this be accomplished using the Java driver? I had previously attempted to accomplish this with

```
collection.updateOne(Filters.eq("_id", new ObjectId(1)), new Document("$set", newDocument));
```

However, this method produces the following result instead:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    field1: "goodbye"
    field2: 2,
    field3: 3,
    listField: [
        {
            subField3: ...
        },
        {
            subField3: ...
        }
    ]
}
```

The issue with this is that the listField field is being *replaced* with the new field. I want each document within listField to be *updated* with the new sub fields instead. What should I be doing differently to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the update that you want, in words?

Comment: Basically as the title says. I have a document that contains a list of documents. I construct a second document that also contains a list of documents with the same field name. Within each of those documents, there is a new field I want to add to each document in the old one. Currently instead of updating the documents within the list, it replaces each one.

Comment: The first step is to figure out how to accomplish your task using the MongoDB shell. Once you've done that it's generally straightforward to write Java driver code to do the same.  I think you'll need to use aggregation to merge the documents, specifically the [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) operator.  Depending on where/how everything is stored you may need to use `$mergeObjects` in the pipeline of a [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage.